# Information lost while adding a list into a list

Tags: r

I am trying the following code, with R 2.13:

```
aa <- list()
aa["test"] <- list(x1=5,x2=7)
```

What I get is:

```
> aa
$test
[1] 5
```

but I would like something closer to:

```
$test
 $x1 5
 $x2 7
```

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't you also get a warning? The warning should suggest that maybe you're using the wrong number of square brackets.

Comment: @joran: Yes, I did get a warning, and you are right, I was using the wrong number of square brackets!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, just found what I was doing wrong!

```
aa[["test"]] <- list(x1=5,x2=7)
```

Does the trick!